# Reading in Data

Tags: python

I am learning how to read data into Python and I am stuck on the below few items in an assignment to make my current code below work.

The function read_dow has 2 parameters "file_path", which contains a string to the path of a dataset and "num_lines", which is an integer.

- Read in each row from "file_path".
- Replace all instances of the new line character "\n" with an empty string ("").
  Hint: Use the replace function of a string
- Separate the columns using a comma as a delimiter
  Hint: Use the split method of a string
- Append the separated row of data without the "\n" character to a list.
- Stop reading in new rows once you have read in "num_lines" lines.
- Return a nested list where each element in the list is a row of data.

_

```
def read_dow(file_path, num_lines=5):
'''

Reads in num lines of data from file_path.

Parameters
----------
file_path: string containing file path to a dataset
num_lines: integer containing the number of lines to read

Returns
-------
Nested List of data read in from the file_path
'''
with open(file_path, 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        line.replace('\n','')
        line.split(",")
        print(line)

new_list = []
    for num_lines in fin:
        new_list.append(num_lines)
```

### Here is the code that is running to test the answer.

```
# Reading in 3 lines of data and testing your answer
ans_3lines = read_dow('data/dow_jones_index.data', num_lines=3)
sol_3lines = [
['quarter', 'stock', 'date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume',
 'percent_change_price', 'percent_change_volume_over_last_wk', 
'previous_weeks_volume',
 'next_weeks_open', 'next_weeks_close', 
'percent_change_next_weeks_price', 'days_to_next_dividend',
 'percent_return_next_dividend'],
['1', 'AA', '1/7/2011', '15.82', '16.72', '15.78', '16.42', 
'239655616', '3.79267', '', '', '16.71',
 '15.97', '-4.42849', '26', '0.182704'],
['1', 'AA', '1/14/2011', '16.71', '16.71', '15.64', '15.97', 
'242963398', '-4.42849', '1.380223028',
 '239655616', '16.19', '15.79', '-2.47066', '19', '0.187852']
]
assert_equal(ans_3lines, sol_3lines, msg='Your answer does not match 
the solutions')

# Reading in 5 lines of data and testing your answer
ans_5lines = read_dow('data/dow_jones_index.data')
sol_5lines = [
['quarter', 'stock', 'date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume',
 'percent_change_price', 'percent_change_volume_over_last_wk', 
'previous_weeks_volume',
 'next_weeks_open', 'next_weeks_close', 
'percent_change_next_weeks_price', 'days_to_next_dividend',
 'percent_return_next_dividend'],
['1', 'AA', '1/7/2011', '15.82', '16.72', '15.78', '16.42', 
'239655616', '3.79267', '', '', '16.71',
 '15.97', '-4.42849', '26', '0.182704'],
['1', 'AA', '1/14/2011', '16.71', '16.71', '15.64', '15.97', 
'242963398', '-4.42849', '1.380223028',
 '239655616', '16.19', '15.79', '-2.47066', '19', '0.187852'],
['1', 'AA', '1/21/2011', '16.19', '16.38', '15.60', '15.79', 
'138428495', '-2.47066', '-43.02495926',
 '242963398', '15.87', '16.13', '1.63831', '12', '0.189994'],
['1', 'AA', '1/28/2011', '15.87', '16.63', '15.82', '16.13', 
'151379173', '1.63831', '9.355500109',
 '138428495', '16.18', '17.14', '5.93325', '5', '0.185989']
]
assert_equal(ans_5lines, sol_5lines, msg='Your answer does not match 
the solutions')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? You haven't called the function.

Comment: You haven't told us what exactly the problem is that you observe, but when looking at the code, it becomes clear that you've mixed up quite a few things: (1) instead of doing something with each line of the file (except printing it), you manipulate the file path; (2) instead of appending the given number of lines to a list, you try to append the number itself; (3) you try to append it to the file path not to a list, which cannot possibly work; (4) instead of returning a list with the file data, you return the file handle

Comment: None of the `str` methods you call change the string in place; they return a *new* string. `line.stop` doesn't even exist; there wouldn't be  string method to control the loop.

Comment: Also note how you are supposed to replace the newline character with an empty string (`''`), but you try to replace with a space character (`' '`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of the things you're doing inside the loop. My suggestion is to remove them and start from a clean loop (you may keep a print inside).

Now in order to only print the lines you want, you need to indeed `append` only the ones you need into a list.

```
lines_you_want = [] # This is how you create a list
lines_you_want.append(line) # This is how you append a line into the list
```

I'll leave the rest to you :)

Comment: Using `for line in fin` actually was one of the few things in the code that made sense.

Comment: @mkrieger1 you're right, it does run readlines() by default, my bad. I updated my answer

Comment: Ok, I think this is starting to make sense now.  How do I have it stop reading lines once it has read a certain number of rows?